Is it possible to calculate $\int_1^n \frac{(n-1) n u}{(n-u) (u-1)} \, du$?
Let $n>2$ be an integer. I want to calculate - or at least set limits on - the integral
$$\int_1^n \frac{(n-1) n u}{(n-u) (u-1)} \, du$$
Clearly, the problem with the definite integral is that there are poles at $u={1,n}$.
I have tried taking limits as $u \rightarrow {1,n}$ but this still leaves me with $\log 0$ in the result.
My next approach was to find principal values at $u={1,n}$. First calculate the antiderivative
$$\int \frac{(n-1) n u}{(n-u) (u-1)} \, du = n (\log(1-u)-n \log(u-n))$$
The average of this expression at $u=1\pm \epsilon$ is
$$\frac{1}{2} n \left(\log (1-n+\epsilon ))+\log (-\epsilon )+\log (\epsilon)-n (\log (1-n-\epsilon)\right)$$
The corresponding expression at $u=n \pm \epsilon$ is
$$\frac{1}{2} n \left(\log (1-n-\epsilon)-n (\log (-\epsilon )+\log (\epsilon ))+\log (1-n+\epsilon)\right)$$
In both cases, we hit the same problem:
$$\underset{\epsilon \to 0}{\text{lim}}\log (\epsilon ) = -\infty$$
And here, I draw a blank. I almost certainly have to resign myself to the definite integral being either infinite or incalculable. But I would be grateful for any insights or suggestions.

I'm not sure I can answer the whole question, but
$$\int_1^n \frac{(n-1) n u}{(n-u) (u-1)} \, du$$
is finite only if
$$\int_1^n \frac{u}{(n-u) (u-1)} \, du$$
is, and that's a little simpler.
My best guess is that finiteness is unlikely to depend much on $n$, so I'm going to look at $n = 2$. Now we have
$$Q = \int_1^2 \frac{u}{(2-u) (u-1)} \, du$$
Fortunately, partial fractions works nicely here, and we get
$$
\frac{1}{(2-u)(u-1)} = \frac{1}{2-u} + \frac{1}{u-1}
$$
so the integral becomes
\begin{align}
Q 
&= \int_1^2 \frac{u}{(2-u) (u-1)} \, du \\
&= \int_1^2 \frac{u}{(2-u)} \, du + \int_1^2 \frac{u}{(u-1)} \, du\\
\end{align}
To remove the messiness of poles at both ends, let's split that at $\frac32$:
\begin{align}
Q 
&= \int_1^2 \frac{u}{(2-u)} \, du + \int_1^2 \frac{u}{(u-1)} \, du\\
&= \int_1^\frac32 \frac{u}{(2-u)} \, du + \int_1^\frac32 \frac{u}{(u-1)} \, du +  \int_\frac32^2 \frac{u}{(2-u)} \, du + \int_\frac32^2 \frac{u}{(u-1)} \, du\\
\end{align}
The first pair constitutes a nice clean integral and an integral with a pole only at $u = 1$. Let's look at the second one: it's
\begin{align}
Q_1 
&= \int_1^\frac32 \frac{u}{(u-1)} \, du  \\
&= \int_0^\frac12 \frac{v+1}{v} \, dv  \\
&= \int_0^\frac12 1 + \frac{1}{v} \, dv  \\
\end{align}
Sadly, this integral is divergent, so the whole thing is divergent.
So I'd say that your integral for the case $n = 2$ doesn't converge on the interval $[0, 2]$.

$$\frac{(n-1)\, n\, u}{(n-u) (u-1)}=\frac{n}{u-1}-\frac{n^2}{u-n}$$
$$\int\frac{(n-1)\, n\, u}{(n-u) (u-1)}\,du=n (\log (| 1-u| )-n \log (| u-n| ))$$
Now, consider
$$I(\epsilon)=\int_{1+\epsilon}^{n-\epsilon}\frac{(n-1)\, n\, u}{(n-u) (u-1)}\,du$$ and use series expansion around $\epsilon=0$
$$I(\epsilon)=n (n+1) \log (n-1)\color{red}{-n(n+1) \log (\epsilon )}-$$ $$n(n+1) \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\epsilon^k} {k\,(n-1)^k }$$
Notice that
$$ \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac {\epsilon^k} {k\,(n-1)^k }=\log \left(1-\frac{\epsilon}{n-1}\right)$$
If you take $n=10$ and $\epsilon=\frac 1{10}$ the above expansion would give
$$\log (89)+109 \log (90)=494.968$$ while the exact value is
$$110\log (89)=493.750$$

Hi @Claude Leibovici. Correct me if I am wrong, but doesn't this then lead to $\log \left( 1 - \frac{\epsilon}{n-1} \right) = \log(1) = 0$ as $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$?

The antiderivative on $(1,n)$ is rather $$n (\log|1-u|-n \log|u-n|)=n\log\frac{u-1}{(n-u)^n},$$ so your integral (of a positive function) is doubly divergent: it equals $$n\left[\log\frac{u-1}{(n-u)^n}\right]_1^n=\log(+\infty)-\log(0^+)=(+\infty)-(-\infty)=+\infty.$$

Many thanks for the responses
